# How to fix top position in column in flutter?

Tags: flutter

If I add widgets in column, the top of column is going up.(picture 2)

Is there any way to fixed the top of column?(picture 3)[image]

picture1

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("Test1")
  ]
)
```

picture2

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("Test1"),
    Text("Test2")
  ]
)
```

Comment: add more details.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far

Comment: if the outer black box in pic3 has fixed size. then-> inside black bordered box use -> `BlackBox(child:Column(children:[Spacer(),Expanded(child:Column(children:[Text('1'),Text('2),],),),],),)`

Comment: ok wait please.

Comment: It seems like you want your content to start halfway through the page. In this case, one solution is to use a LayoutBuilder, get the middle point of the page, and then add your column there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated what you want from the picture attached above:

Make two `Expanded` widgets and let the 2nd `Expanded` widget take a `Column` where you will put your `Text`s widgets:

```dart
   return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox(),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: SizedBox.expand(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Test 1',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Test 2',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Test 3',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

RESULT:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use **mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start**